# How to add google maps to a blazorwasm application

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have just started learning c# in school, and now have a project, whre I have to implement at map on a webpage.

#### What is the problem

Well Im almost completly new to c#, .NET and Blazor. So I am in a terrible spot. My plan is to have a ASP .NET core RESTapi, which is feeding a blazorwasm application. I can only find support for blazorserver, which is not ideal, since I also wanna make it a PWA.

#### Why I am not giving up on the PWA

This is a school project, but the school have found us a "customer", so if I make the best application, I could go ahead and nget a pretty decent salery.
That is why I wanna make it a PWA.

I can only find stuff like this:
https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/how-can-i-add-google-maps-to-a-blazor-application

and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF1UgVv7Njs
which only shows support for blazor server, and then I can't make it a PWA.

It is not restricted to be google maps, but have found almost no apis for maps else where.

### TL;DR

Do any one know have to add google maps support to a blazorwasm application, or any other map api I can use with some functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is definitely possible. But it is a bit workaround in Blazor app. The sample from syncfusion will work for Blazor Wasm. It is not complicated. You are just using javascript api from google maps. Did you try that sample for Blazor Wasm?

Comment: I did a workaround, where I use IJSruntime to call some js functions, and pass some parameters into js. It is not ideal, since the map will be js, and not affect my grade what so ever, which is annoying. I was hoping for a nugget package, like the npm one for react. react-google-maps or what it is called. That would have been usefull. But it is fine, I will just have to add some other functionality, to get my grade up